# What does `ObjectMapper mapper = []` mean in groovy?

Tags: groovy, gretty

I'm new to groovy, and I'm reading the source of a project [gretty](https://github.com/groovypp/gretty/blob/master/gretty/src/org/mbte/gretty/JacksonCategory.groovy)

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
class JacksonCategory {
static final ObjectMapper mapper = []
    ...
}
```

I don't understand the code `ObjectMapper mapper = []`, what does `[]` mean here? I thought it's a `list`, but how to assign it to a `ObjectMapper`?

---

**UPDATE**

Depends on [Dunes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130548/what-does-objectmapper-mapper-mean-in-groovy/7130657#7130657), seems `[]` means `invocation of default constructor`. So, it means:

```
static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
```

But:

```
String s = []
println s // -> it's `[]` not ``
```

And

```
Integer i = []
```

throws exception:

```
Caught: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '[]' 
with class 'java.util.ArrayList' to class 'java.lang.Integer' 
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '[]' with class  
'java.util.ArrayList' to class 'java.lang.Integer'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a call to the default constructor of ObjectMapper.

http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-using-lists-and-maps-as.html

It seems `[]` is always created as an empty ArrayList, but when assigned to a separate type groovy tries to do type coercion and find an appropriate constructor.

With strings it just calls the toString method on the list and makes that the string. For objects it looks for constructors with the appropriate number and type of arguments.

Groovy does not expect to have to do this for java library classes that extend Number (Integer, BigDecimal, etc) and throws a ClassCastException instead.

Examples:

```
class A {
    String value;
    A() { this("value"); }
    A(String value) { this.value = value; }
}

def A defaultCons = [];
// equivalent to new A()
def A argsCons = ["x"];
// equivalent to new A("x")
def list = [1,2];
// literal ArrayList notation
def String str = [];
// equivalent to str = "[]"

println "A with default constructor: " + defaultCons.value;
println "A with String arg constructo: " + argsCons.value;
println "list: " + list;
println "str: " + str;
```

Comment: thank you. But I found something different: `String s = []`, then the `s` is the string `[]`

Comment: That's because string is a special case. Groovy just thinks you forgot to put quotation marks around `[]`

Comment: please see my updated question. And is there any article to explain this feature?

Comment: See the link I found. It explains how Groovy uses Lists and Maps to invoke constructors of Classes.

Comment: Just to clarify the string situation: it's not that Groovy is "adding quotes" - it's that behind the scenes Groovy is coercing the object types.  It's like you actually typed `String s = [] as String` which means `[].asType(String)` which becomes `[].toString()`.  The String representation of an empty List is `"[]"`.  List and Map have some special `asType` handling to allow them to convert into most GroovyBeans or JavaBeans.