# What is the Groovy way to copy arguments to properties in a Groovy class?

Tags: groovy, constructor

Given an object with properties and a constructor, I wish to copy the constructor arguments into properties, and then do some additional work in the Constructor.

```
import groovy.transform.TupleConstructor

@TupleConstructor
class Thing{
    def one
    def two

    public Thing(one, two){
       doSomething()
    }

    def doSomething(){
        println "doing something with one : $one and two: $two"
    }
}


println new Thing(1, 2).dump()
```

This will successfully copy the args to the properties if I do nothing else in the constructor, but if I call "doSomething()" in the constructor, the properties are not copied.

I'm seeking "The Groovy" Way for copying args to properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As tim_yates [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10451509/581845), the TupleConstructor AST transformation won't do anything if you have another constructor defined (you can blame [this line](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/05b9f3be0c6d7b74a99e05113e4c3cc083e12e9d/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/transform/TupleConstructorASTTransformation.java#L104) of code =P). If you *need* to run some other code in the construction of the object, you may add that in a static factory method and use that instead of the tuple constructor directly:

```
import groovy.transform.TupleConstructor

@TupleConstructor
class Thing {
    def one
    def two

    def doSomething(){
        println "doing something with one : $one and two: $two"
    }

    static create(...args) {
        def thing = new Thing(*args)
        thing.doSomething()
        thing
    }
}


println Thing.create(1, 2).dump()
```

Notice that i'm using a variable-argument static method to receive an arbitrary number of parameters and then calling the tuple constructor with those parameters (used the "spread" (`*`) operator for that).

Unfortunately, the TupleConstructor AST transform does not seem to have an option for adding the tuple constructor as private, which would be useful in this case.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `TupleConstructor`, it will not run if you have defined your own constructor.

And as you have defined a duplicate constructor to the one `TupleConstructor` will generate in the bytecode, even doing `@TupleConstructor( force=true )` won't help you as you will just get a `java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate method name&signature in class file Thing`

The best I can think of at the moment is to do:

```
class Thing{
    def one
    def two

    public Thing( Map params ){
       this.class.declaredFields.grep { !it.synthetic }.name.each { name ->
         this[ name ] = params[ name ]
       }
       doSomething()
    }

    def doSomething(){
        println "doing something with one : $one and two: $two"
    }
}


println new Thing(one:1, two:2).dump()
```

Though there is probably a better way that I'm missing

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072307/copy-groovy-class-properties) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169601/how-to-assign-all-matching-properties-from-groovy-object-to-java-object) which are pretty similar to this one...

Comment: This also won't work if Thing extends something, as it won't see the inherited properties